# Modify position calculation to alter depth perception

Tags: jquery, html, math, css

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qw1dgsuh/).

Also, here is a copy in plain HTML for convenience and record.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test shadows</title>
<style>
body {
    cursor: url('http://solar-center.stanford.edu/images/metallic.gif'), auto;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
.castsshadow {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #50535C;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
.castsshadow div {
    z-index: 2;
    margin: -10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background: lightgrey;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {

        $(".castsshadow").each(function (i) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var width = $(this).width();
            var height = $(this).height();
            $(this).html(
                "<div>X Axis : " + e.pageX + " Y Axis : " + e.pageY + "<br>" + "X Offset : " + offset.left + " Y Offset : " + offset.top + "<br>" + "Height : " + height + " Width : " + width + "<br>" + "X Center : " + (offset.left + (width / 2)) + " Y Center : " + (offset.top + (height / 2)) + "</div>");
            $(this).css({
                boxShadow: -(e.pageX - (offset.left + (width / 2))) / 5 + "px " + (-(e.pageY - (offset.top + (height / 2))) / 5) + "px 10px -5px #404040"
            });
        });

    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="div1" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 1</div></div>
      <div id="div2" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 2</div></div>
      <div id="div3" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 3</div></div>
      <div id="div4" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 4</div></div>
      <p>This is a gap.</p>
      <div id="div5" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 5</div></div>
      <div id="div5" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 6</div></div>
      <div id="div5" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 7</div></div>
      <div id="div5" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 8</div></div>
      <div id="div5" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 9</div></div>
      <div id="div5" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 10</div></div>
      <div id="div5" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 11</div></div>
      <div id="div5" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 12</div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am looking to alter the calculations so that it appears the pointer/sun is closer to the "raised" divs.  This would mean divs further away would have their shadows MUCH further away (probably on an exponential scale?) and when you sweep your mouse over a specific div, its shadow would sweep by quickly.

What point of the calculation of position would achieve this?  I tried multiplying the e.pageY but this doesn't help.  As you can tell, I am not great at maths, which is why I put so much data in the divs for testing.

Comment: That's a nice effect, though very cpu intensive. To change the shadow "length" increase your dividing factor (currently 10 in the fiddle, 5 in your code above)

Comment: Yep, lots of calculations always firing when moving the mouse.  It's for a fancy browser based game concept I am playing with.